# Хранение фото при помощи MySQL на Tomcat сервере

Tags: html, mysql, jsp, tomcat

Необходимо организовать загрузку юзерром фото на сайт. Планируется обычной формой - передача с сохранением ссылки в бд. 
Может ли Tomcat сохранить фото, если да то как? Если что поправте советом. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вы распрекрасно можете сохранять файлы как на в файловой системе так и в бд в виде blob. Первый вариант конечно проще

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html

Comment: Как раз это читаю

Comment: Там описано как распарсить до потока файла (InputStream). Не знаю что дальше с ним делать..

Comment: item.write(new File(filename));

Comment: item.write(new File(item.getName())) -> java.io.FileNotFoundException

Comment: a а имя то какое

Comment: @ Stranger in the Q, имя загружаемого файла logo.gif

Comment: Абсолютный путь

Answer (score 1):

Файл сохранен:

```
factory.setRepository(new File("/home/mihail/IdeaProjects/Handmaker2/src/main/webapp/images"));
```

...

```
item.write(new File(factory.getRepository() + "/" + item.getName()));
```

Cпасибо @Stranger in the Q!

Comment: сохранить это одно, а как потом отдать на страницу? это несколько другая проблема. это касается по хранению и в базе и в файловой системе.